# Align two divs to the right of one

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm making a website for someone and I'm kind of rusty with my html/css, and I really need side navigation on this site.

I have the sidebar (#menu), then I want two divs (#slider on top of #container) to the left of #menu.

How can I do this? Code is below, you also might want to know that #slider is a photo slider I got online:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Arial; background-color: #eeeeee; background-image: url(Images/bg.png); background-position: bottom; background-repeat: repeat-x; height: 100%; background-attachment: fixed; color: #333333;}
div#menu {float:left;margin-left: 25%; margin-right:25%; font-size: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 10%; border: 1px solid #cccccc; text-align: center; word-spacing: 15px; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 10px;}
div#container {padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%; width: 40%; border: 1px solid #cccccc; text-align: left; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 10px;}
a {color: #666666; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {color: #333333; text-decoration: underline;}
ul, li {list-style-type: none;}
#slider {width:600px;height:300px; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%; margin-top: 10px;}
div.navBulletsWrapper {display:none;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="menu">
<li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
<Br>
<li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="products.htm">Products</a></li>
<Br>
<li><a href="news.htm">News</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></div></li>

<div id="slider">
        <img src="1.jpg" />
        <img src="2.jpg" />
        <img src="3.jpg" />
    </div>

<div id="container">
Placeholder text.
</div>
```

Comment: you want urgent help?.. Better make fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget your non validating html for a while, though there is much to say about it.

Your main issue is a lack of structure, you'll find it easier to align your slider and container if they are inside a common div. Your code should look like this (schematically):

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.htm">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.htm">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
   <div id="slider">
    <img src="1.jpg" />
    <img src="2.jpg" />
    <img src="3.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div id="container">
     Placeholder text.
   </div>
</div>
```

That way, you can float #menu and #main as you wish (right or left).

On to other issues in your code, always wrap li inside a ul or ol, and never use br to make vertical space, prefer using margin or padding. Html is for document structure only, CSS takes care of the visualization part.

Answer (score 0):

First clean up your HTML. Run it through the W3C validator if you're not sure what to fix. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Do you want slider and container inside of menu? If so, you've closed your first div too soon. Also I'm not sure your margins as percentages will give you the desired feel you're going for.

Please be a little more specific with your question and fix up your markup.

Comment: Sorry I meant I want slider and container to the left of menu!

Comment: Fix up your last li :) <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></div></li>

Comment: The div is closed before the li